# Google anlytics or Firebase analytics for web/native platforms?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

Our app was hybrid app and we also have a website.

So we just used 'web' google analytics so far.

Now we are converting some pages to react native.

I see there are several options available for unified (web/native) reporting.

1. I'd like to use 'web' google analytics with react native if I could, but not sure if I could do that.
2. use `screenview` or `pageview` hit-type from both web and native, although I'm not sure If one could send `pageview` hit-type from native (or react-native)
3. connect firebase to GA (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2587086) not sure what it actually does.
4. use bigquery (https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-firebase-analytics-big-query) although I don't want to go this route because it's seems too much work to set up..

How do you organize analytics when you have both `web` and `app` ?